# Proto MessageDifferencer::Equals Performance comparison

Tags: protocol-buffers

In the new versions of `protobuf`, there is a class `MessageDifferencer` which provides methods to compare two `proto` messages in C++. I wanted to ask what would be the performance difference in comparing two messages using `SerializeToString` vs using `MessageDifferencer::Equals`?

Comment: MessageDifferencer's gonna be faster, serializing prots to string is not exactly cheap. How much faster, depends a lot on what kind of protos you have, so why don't you just run a simple benchmark?
Also if you have big protos, RAM savings from not having to serialize them to string might be significant.